# How to pass in connection string when overriding UserNamePasswordValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am overriding UserNamePasswordValidator in my WCF service and I want to validate the username and password against an SQL database.  Is there anyway to pass the connection string into the PasswordValidator class?  I should also have mentioned that my class is in a separate to the main WCF service.

```
public class MyCustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        //TODO: how to pass in connection string??
        connectionString = "Data Source=MyDataSource;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;User ID=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword";

        // connect to database and validate crendentials...

        if (!valid)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Access Denied.");
        }
    }
}
```

Config section:

```
<userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyCompany.Services.Validation.MyCustomUserNameValidator, MyCompany.Services.Validation"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your `connectionString` in config file in `<appsettings>`

```
<addkey="DbConnection" value ="Your Connection String"/>
```

and and use in `MyCustomUserNameValidator`
class as

```
ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.WebConfig["DbConnection"].ToString();
```

*** EDIT:**  `ConfigurationManager does actually read from the web.config. the exact solution was: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]` was the  answer

Comment: I should have mentioned MyCustomUserNameValidator is in a separate dll to the main WCF service.  If there is a way to call the main web.config I'd be happy with that, but having a second config file will lead to confusion and frustration for other developers should the settings not match the main web config.

Comment: you can acces the config as `var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("MyDll.dll.config");`

Comment: Or,  
Just add an app.config file to the DLL project, and make sure you read the configuration settings from inside the DLL. When deployed, your config file needs to have the name "MyDLL.dll.config" (assuming your DLL is named "MyDLL.dll") and be in the same folder as the DLL.

The following code should return my connectionstring from my dll :

`return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbConnection"];`

Comment: Thanks.  ConfigurationManager does actually read from the web.config.  the exact solution was: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]